# C# Visual Studio 2017. Words changed order in text boxes and labels

Tags: textbox, visual-studio-2017

I just started using Visual Studio 2017.  I noticed a problem with text boxes, labels and the captions on forms.  In a text box I programically stamp the date: System.DateTime.Now.  It shows up as 'PM 2:15 12/20/2017' not '12/20/2017 2:15 PM'.  I tried hard coding the date but the text box keeps rearranging it back to that first pattern.  labels do something similar.  The text for the label was 'Designated Date:'.  At runtime the colon comes first, then the words asthis ':Designated Date'.  In addition the text alignment property is opposite.  It's set at right but shows at left.   I googled this problem and couldn't find any thing on it. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

you can use any of these combinations

```
  this.textBox1.Text = DateTime.Now.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy");
   //or 
  this.textBox1.Text = DateTime.Now.ToString("hh:mm:ss");
  //or
  this.textBox1.Text = DateTime.Now.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy" +" "+ "hh:mm");
```

etc.

Comment: Thank you for answering so quickly but that doesn't work. I used this line of code:  textBox1.Text = DateTime.Now.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy" + " " + HH:mm"); and the result is "14:00 12/21/2017"  The same thing happens in labels. The words get reversed.

Comment: For me, using the line textBox1.Text = DateTime.Now.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy" + " " + "HH:mm");  the result is: 12/21/2017 8:42.